# Why is my HTTPClient running out of connections when using pooled connection manager?

Tags: java, scala, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache HttpComponents 4.5.1. in a Scala project, however Scala is unlikely to be  my issue. Here is a JUnit 4 style test.

```
@Test def closableHttpClientWithPoolingCmTest{
  val poolingHttpConnectionManager: PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()
  poolingHttpConnectionManager setMaxTotal (12)
  poolingHttpConnectionManager setDefaultMaxPerRoute (8)
  def client = HttpClients custom () setConnectionManager  (poolingHttpConnectionManager) build ()
  for (i  <- 0 to 12 ){
    def response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.yahoo.com"));
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity)
    response.close();
  }
}
```

This test hangs, because we run out of connections. What am I missing?I consume the entity and close the response. Do I need to close anything else besides `response`? 
Please help.

Comment: Use context logging for connection management as shown here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html and post the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client definition should be a `val` not a `def`

`def`is evaluated every time `client` is called, making a new pool for every invocation. Instead with `val` your pool will be constructed once and reused.

`def client = HttpClients custom () setConnectionManager  (poolingHttpConnectionManager) build ()`

should become

`val client = HttpClients custom () setConnectionManager  (poolingHttpConnectionManager) build ()`

Comment: @rahib, I am having trouble in a single run in the loop itself. Did the code you posted workw tihout hanging?

Comment: @Prashant I did not run the code. Your loop will create a maximum of 156 connections as you do not reuse instances of `client`.

Comment: Wow! @rahib, that was it. Don't know why I didn't realize it on my own. I will take a printout of this as one of the dumbest mistakes (AND as one of my silliest replies to a comment (above) :)) of my career and put up on desk. Thanks for the help!